# Pulling out data from HTML form and saving it in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

How can I get data from a HTML form and save it do MongoDB with node and express? Currently I can't get the data in the format that my models require. Can you help me out what I'm missing, please? Please don't mind if there is word that you dont understand. I translated this to english.

In the HTML I file have two input fields: Ingredient and amount which I need to group together. This group of inputs exists 10 times in the page.

```
<form action="/diary/<%= day._id %>/showday" method="post" name="meal">
        <div class="">
          <input type="text" name="meal[title]" value="">
        </div>
        <% for(i = 0; i<10; i++) { %>    
        <div>
          <fieldset>
            <select name="meal[ingredients]">
              <% ingredients.forEach(function(singleIngredient){ %>
                  <option value="<%= singleIngredient %>" name="<%= singleIngredient %>"><%= singleIngredient.aine %></option>
            <%  }); %>
            </select>
            <input type="number" name="meal[amount]" placeholder="gr">
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <% } %>
        <div>
          <button>Submit!</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

Data I get from the form is in two arrays which I cannot format correctly no matter what I've tried. I also tried with fieldset tag, but it did not change the format of the data.

I have Mongoose models like below:

```
ingredient.js
var mongoose = mongoose = require("mongoose");
var ingredientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ingredient: String,
  kcal: Number,
  protein: Number,
  carbs: Number,
  fat: Number,
  addinfo: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Ingredient", ingredientSchema);

meals.js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Ingredient = require('../models/ingredient');
var mealSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  ingredients: [{ingredient: Ingredient.schema, amount: Number}],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Meal", mealSchema);

day.js
var mongoose = mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Meal = require('../models/meal');
var daySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  day: Date,
  meals: [Meal.schema]
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Day", daySchema);
```

app.js looks like below. In app.js I tried to put form data into the format of the model but when I log the result it looks a bit different than seed data what I have and I'm assuming that this is the reason why this is not working.

```
Day.findById(req.params.id, function(err, day) {
if (err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.redirect("/diary");
} else {
  var singleMeal = [];
  var singleIngredient = {};
  var singleIngredientArray = [];
  var singleIngredientAmount = "";

  var len = req.body.meal.amount.length;
  for (i=0; i < len; i++) {

//MODIFY DATA SO THAT ITS IN RIGHT FORMAT AND TAKE ONLY INGREDIENTS WHICH HAS AMOUNT ABOVE 0
    if (req.body.meal.amount[i] !== "") {
      singleIngredient.ingredient = req.body.meal.ingredient[i];
      singleIngredient.amount = Number(req.body.meal.amount[i]);
      singleIngredientArray.push(singleIngredient);
singleMeal.push(singleIngredientArray[i]);
console.log(singleIngredient.ingredient + "<<<< ==== singleIngredient.ingredient");
console.log(singleIngredientArray);
console.log(singleMeal[i].title + "<<<< ==== singleMeal.title");
//--- THIS IS WHERE THE GAME ENDS ----
        } else {
        }
      }         
Meal.create(singleMeal, function(err, meal) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            } else {
              day.meals.push(meal);
              day.save();
              res.redirect("/diary/" + day._id + "/showday");
            }
          });
        };
      });
    });
```

This is what I get in console when I log like in the app.js:

```
[object Object]<<<< ==== singleIngredientArray
{ _id: 59731a5156809d5ee310aad0,
  ingredient: 'Kaurahiutale',
  kcal: 100,
  protein: 2,
  carb: 50,
  fat: 1,
  addinfo: '',
  __v: 0 }<<<< ==== singleIngredient.ingredient
undefined<<<< ==== singleMeal[i].title
```

I also got sometimes when I tried something else (dont even remember how because I've tried almost everything except the right way) result like below, but it has \r\n chars in it and this looks a bit different than seed data.

```
{ ingredient: '{ _id: 59731357eee39a59fb5a5878,\r\n  ingredient: \'oatmeal\',\r\n  kcal: 100,\r\n  protein: 2,\r\n  carb: 50,\r\n  fat: 1,\r\n  addinfo: \'fineli.fi\',\r\n  __v: 0 }',
  amount: 3 }
{ ingredient: '{ _id: 59731357eee39a59fb5a5878,\r\n  ingredient: \'oatmeal\',\r\n  kcal: 100,\r\n  protein: 2,\r\n  carb: 50,\r\n  fat: 1,\r\n  addinfo: \'fineli.fi\',\r\n  __v: 0 }',
  amount: 3 }
```

When I start app this seed data is loaded to Mongo and it is working ok.
seed.js:

```
    var ingredients = [
  {
    ingredient: "oatmeal",
    kcal: 100,
    protein: 2,
    carb: 50,
    fat: 1,
    addinfo: ""
  },

  {
    ingredient: "Whey80",
    kcal: 150,
    protein: 80,
    carb: 2,
    fat: 1,
    addinfo: ""
  },
  {
    ingredient: "Tomato",
    kcal: 20,
    protein: 1,
    carb: 4,
    fat: 0,
    addinfo: ""
  }
];

var meals = [{
    title: "Breakfast",
    ingredients: [{ingredient: ingredients[1], amount: 5}]},
  {
  title: "Some snack",
  ingredients: [{
    ingredient: {
        ingredient: "Whey80",
        kcal: 150,
        protein: 80,
        carb: 4,
        fat: 0,
        addinfo: ""
      },
    amount: 40},
    {
      ingredient: {
ingredient: "Whey80",
          kcal: 150,
          protein: 80,
          carb: 4,
          fat: 0,
          addinfo: ""
      },
      amount: 40},
  ]}
];
var days = [{
  day: "010101",
  meals: [meals[0], meals[1]]
}];
```

I really would appreciate if you can point me where I'm going wrong with this.

Comment: Go small steps to figure out your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I will go through this in smaller steps and check where I'm going wrong direction. I'll come back to this later if needed.

Comment: Well the clue for the answer was the format how HTML form returned the data and taking small steps as Lazyexpert suggested. It was two arrays in an object, not just two arrays :) Good night sleep and some wood chopping helped also.